# How to display multiple images in jsp using a struts2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am getting images from the database and storing all the images in a `filepath( request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath)`. Now am having all the images in the filepath.

Then am getting the images from filepath to

```
private File[] filelist;
```

Now am trying to display the filelist in JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="filelist">
  <img src="<s:property />"/>             
</s:iterator>
```

Output in browser is am getting the filepath of all the images(i can iterate) but images are not loading.

If i put the `<img>` tag in `<a>` and click on the link its displaying "The address wasn't understood". If i enter the link the slash "/" is changing and the image in displaying.

```
<s:iterator value="filelist">
  <a href="<s:property />"/>
    <img src="<s:property />"/>
  </a>
</s:iterator>
```

In Firebug its showing "Could not load image".

I may be wrong in displaying the image so please help how to load the image in JSP.

Comment: Please show the addresses that are printed in your rendered HTML

Comment: <td>
 <img src="F:\Work\StrutsTilesExample\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HobbiesProject\work\getimage\p1.jpg">             
        
 <img src="F:\Work\StrutsTilesExample\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HobbiesProject\work\getimage\p2.jpg">             
 </td>

Comment: You shouldn't store anything under system folder.

Comment: Am having all the images under the path.If i paste the url in browser and click enter then the images are displaying and the slash is changing from "\" to "/". Before it shows "The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (f) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

    You might need to install other software to open this address."

Comment: I did iteration in jsp and its working.But i don how to do with sturts tags.<%
     File f=new File(application.getRealPath("/work/getimage/")); 
       File []f2=f.listFiles();
       String [] fileNames = f.list();
       for(int ii=0;ii<f2.length;ii++)
       {
         if(f2[ii].isFile())
         {
         %>
      <a HREF="<%="work/getimage/"+fileNames[ii]%>">
        <img border="0" src="<%="work/getimage/"+fileNames[ii]%>" >
      </a></br>
      <%}
        } %>

Comment: You should probably provide an action to retrieve the image, please see: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html

Comment: Thanks  Quaternion. I will try it.

Comment: @nansjames Please put code in the question, not in comments-it's essentially impossible to read.